# Using a single fragment with multiple layout in Android

Tags: android, xml, layout, fragment

I want to use a single fragment(Only Single Fragment Class that can laod multiple layout) with multiple layout. I have two layout xml files. According to the situation in the run time, i have to switch between the layout xml file. Actually the app has to post a form. If user has to fill the form, a fragment with questionnaire layout must be visible and when the user clicks the submit button, another layout within same fragment must be visible, displaying the results. And if a user has already submitted the form, a fragment with result layout must be visible.

Is it possible? If not please suggest any other feasible alternative.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is that you can have simple `FrameLayout` for the `Fragment` view. Then use `LayoutInflater` to inflate corresponding view and add it to the `FrameLayout`. You can switch the layout by removing the existing view and inflate other to replace it.

Code would be something like this:

```
private FrameLayout mContainer;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContainer = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_framelayout, null);

    onSubmittedStateChanged(SubmittedState.SUBMITTED); // OR SubmittedState.NOT_SUBMITTED

    return mContainer;
}

public void onSubmittedStateChanged(SubmittedState state) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mContainer.removeAllViews();

    switch (state) {
    case SubmittedState.SUBMITTED:
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.submitted, mContainer);
        break;
    case SubmittedState.NOT_SUBMITTED:
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.not_submitted, mContainer);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i do it, can u give me example. I tried to use layout inflater but it didn't work.

Comment: i tried your code but it didn't work. can you upload the example of fragmen_framelayout, submitted and not_sumbitted layouts. Actually i am calling a fragment from an activity. And activity itself has a layout.

Comment: fragment_framelayout is FrameLayout defined in xml, submitted and not_submitted layouts are your own layouts for those states in xml. How it didn't work?

Comment: I have a button in a activity, when i press, it calls the fragment and  one of the layout should be loaded via layoutinflater. but the problem is, also the button from the activity is loaded. Also your code works when i have to decide which layout to load while the fragment is created. But i need to change the layout within the fragment. When i press some button in no_sumbitted layout, it must load the submitted layout within framgnet.

Comment: Since both submitted and not_submitted layouts are in the same Fragment you can call the onSubmittedStateChanged, which will remove the not_submitted layout and add submitted to the Fragment.

Comment: when i call the fragment from activity, the content of both layout, activity's layout and fragment' layout are seen in in UI.

Comment: Maybe you should have new Activity which will only display the submitted/not_submitted Fragment? Hard to say without seeing your application UI.